# class in class with angular 2

Tags: arrays, class, angular

this is my first question so I hope I will ask it properly. So, for my project, I need to create several groups and, in each of them, create several persons. For now, I have created one file of groups and one file of persons who look like this :

```
import { Person} from '../person/person';
export class Group {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    I: Person;
}
```

And :

```
export class Person {
    name: string;
    phone:number;
}
```

Now, when I want to create a mock file for my groups, I tried this :

```
import { Group }   from './group';
import { Person}   from '../person/person';

I: Person= {
    name:"test"
    phone: 25
};
export const GROUPS: Group[] = [
  {id: 1, name: "Chefs d'agence", I:Person},
]
```

(don't pay attention to the name, I'm french) But it didn't work, so I tried this :

```
import { Group }   from './group';
import { Person}   from '../person/person';

export const GROUPS: Group[] = [
  {id: 1, name: "Chefs d'agence", I:Person={name:"test",phone:25},
]
```

But in the end, I finish with this type of error on Group :

```
Type '{ id: number; name: string; I: typeof Individu; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Groupe[]'.
Type '{ id: number; name: string; I: typeof Individu; }' is not assignable to type 'Groupe'.
    Types of property 'I' are incompatible.
      Type 'typeof Individu' is not assignable to type 'Individu'.
        Property 'nom' is missing in type 'typeof Individu'.
```

For now I test it not with an array of Person but just with one Person however I have no idea of how to do it.

Comment: need to look into `Interface`

Comment: `I: Person = new Person(); I.name = "Something"  .......`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're confusing **interfaces** and **classes**.

The code you provided seems to indicate you want to use interfaces.

You could declare the interfaces like this:

```ts
export interface Person {
  name: string;
  phone: string;
}

export interface Group {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  persons: Person[];
}
```

And then, to use them :

```ts
const p: Person = { name: 'Pierre', phone: '01.02.03.04.05' };
const g: Group = { id: 340, name: 'Administrateurs', persons: [p] };
```

Additional notes:

- A phone number is almost NEVER of the type `number` (what if the number starts with zero? what if you need to include the country code or separators, e.g. `+33`?...)
- It's a design choice but I would put the groups in the `Person` interface instead of the opposite like you did. This would result in the following interfaces:

```ts
export interface Group {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

export interface Person {
  name: string;
  phone: string;
  groups: Group[];
}
```

**What's the difference between interfaces and classes?**

**Interfaces** only describe the **shape** of your data. You use them to tell the TypeScript compiler (and your IDE) what type of data is expected at specific points in your code (e.g. this method should return this type of data, this variable should contain this type of object...). Interfaces disappear from your code after TypeScript has been transpiled to JavaScript.

**Classes**, on the other hand, can be **instantiated**. It means they can hold data (in class instances) and implement behavior (in class methods). Even though a TypeScript class be used just to impose a shape to an object (as an interface would), it can do a lot more than that. Also, classes are persisted in the final JavaScript code (after transpiling).

Comment: I was following the tuto of the Tower of Heroes on Angular.io, and in it, they use export class Heroes and not interface, that's why I want to use it like this. 

But I found a way thanks to your explanation, I will post it in another comment (Because I am editing right now, I didn't know Enter was to send the message automatically)

Comment: If I am doing this : 

     `export const GROUPES: Groupe[] = [
       {id: 1, name: "Chefs d'agence",I:[
         {name:'test',phone:'25'},
         {name:'test2',phone:'28'}
         ] },
       {id: 2, name: 'Clients', I:[
         {name:'essai',phone:'46'},
         {name:'essaie2',phone:'28'}]}
     ]`

It works and I can find the person I am looking for in the group that I choose. I think, in angular2, we can use interface almost like class, or I misunderstand something in the tuto.

Thanks for the help, and sorry for my english (I pretty bad in grammar and vocabulary :( )

Comment: In some situations, you can use either a class or an interface. The main difference is that a class can be instantiated, whereas an interface cannot. I have updated my answer to make this point more clear.